# beginner async/await questions

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to understand async/await. Please find two screenshots with question as attachments.

To question 1: awaits waits for release or reject. Is this correct?
[image]
[image]
Thank you for the answers. 
kind regards

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: Among the many problems of [posting pictures of text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) is when you use colour schemes that colour blind people can't read. I have no idea what your actual question is.

Comment: remove the `.then()`, just use `resolve(body)`, this is what will be awaited and stored in `result`

Answer (score 0):

The two versions of your code are almost equivalent. Any function declared using the `async` keyword returns a promise.

As an example, the following function, despite looking like it does nothing Promise-related, will return a Promise:

```
async function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

We can verify this as follows

```
> helloWorld().then(result => console.log(result));
Hello World
```

As the `async` keyword suggests, we are instructing the JavaScript runtime that it should run the function asynchronously. Since the caller of the function needs to receive a result immediately when doing something like `let result = helloWorld()`, `result` contains a Promise which will eventually resolve to the return value of `helloWorld()` (or be rejected if `helloWorld()` throws an error).

So, in your code, there is almost no difference between the top version (`result = await new Promise...`) and the bottom version (`result = new Promise...`): in both cases, your function `asyncData()` will return a Promise which eventually resolves to the request data or rejects if the request fails.

There is one slight difference. In the top version of the code which does `result = await new Promise...`, lines 23 and 24 will only be executed after lines 6-22, so you'll see "Rest call successful" before you see "Return promise". In the bottom version of the code which does `result = new Promise...`, line 23 will be executed immediately, so you'll see "Rest call successful" first.

The reason for this difference is that an `await` statement is akin to placing every line after the `await` statement in a `then` block. The example below illustrates this.

```
async function returnsAPromise() {
    return Promise.resolve("Hello World");
}

// this will log the result first.
async function withAwait() {
    const result = await returnsAPromise();
    console.log(result);
    console.log("rest of function");
}

// this is equivalent to the function above, because of the way await works.
function withEquivalentThen() {
    const result = returnsAPromise();
    result.then(r => {
      console.log(r);
      console.log("rest of function");
    });
}

// this version logs "rest of function" first.
function dontWaitForPromiseThen() {
    const result = returnsAPromise();
    result.then(r => console.log(r));
    console.log("rest of function");

}
```